# SQL grouping into ranges?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table "USER_ACTIVITY" like this:

```
USER_ID, LOGINS, CITY
1         2        NY 
2         4        NY
3         10       NY
15        0        WS
...
```

And I want to have a result like this:

```
CITY, DEAD_USERS, LOW_ACTIVITY, HIGH_ACTIVITY
NY     0           2             1 ....
```

This is about normal Oracle-SQL in Exaplus.

I really do not know how I can specify ranges on my own. Thank you!

Comment: Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: how do you count these values?

Comment: Let us know how you decide if user is dead, highly active or lowly active

Comment: SELECT LOGINS,
   CASE LOGINS WHEN 0 THEN 'dead'
   WHEN LOGINS < 4 THEN '1-3'
   WHEN LOGINS < 25 THEN '4-25'
   ELSE '25+' END
   FROM USER_BASHIRI.USER_ACTIVITY;

Comment: that i tried. it looks correct but everything gets classified '25+' so it always takes the "else" path

Comment: ah it works now. just a simple syntax problem. thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT` with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT City,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN logins = 0 THEN 1 END ) AS dead,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN logins BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 1 END ) AS low_activity,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN logins > 3 THEN 1 END ) AS high_activity
FROM   user_activity
GROUP BY City
```